# Reproduce two distributions as provided on a single plot using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

I want to draw distributions like shown in figure below -- tail of distributions. I have tried following but not quite getting there:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import math

mean1 = 0
variance1 = 1
sigma1 = math.sqrt(variance1)
x = np.linspace(-3,3.5,100, endpoint=True)
plt.plot(x,mlab.normpdf(x,mean1,sigma1))

mean2 = 0.4
variance2 = 2
sigma2 = math.sqrt(variance2)
y = np.linspace(-4,3.5,100, endpoint=False)
plt.plot(x,mlab.normpdf(y,mean2,sigma2))
##plt.axis('off')
plt.yticks([])
plt.xticks([])
plt.show()
```

Any suggestions would be appreciative?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `fill_between`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import math

mean1 = 0
variance1 = 1
sigma1 = math.sqrt(variance1)
x = np.linspace(-3,3.5,100, endpoint=True)
y1 = mlab.normpdf(x,mean1,sigma1)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y1)

mean2 = 0.4
variance2 = 2
sigma2 = math.sqrt(variance2)
y = np.linspace(-4,3.5,100, endpoint=False)
y2 = mlab.normpdf(y,mean2,sigma2)
ax.plot(x,y2)


ax.fill_between(x[:30], y1[:30], color='blue')
ax.fill_between(x[:30], y2[:30], color='green')
ax.fill_between(x[-30:], y1[-30:], y2[-30:], color='red', alpha=0.5)
ax.set_yticks([])
ax.set_xticks([])
plt.savefig('fill_norms.png')
plt.show()
```

[image]

This is a crazy simple example -- see the [cookbook examples](http://matplotlib.org/users/recipes.html#fill-between-and-alpha) and look at the `where` clause; your fill-between highlights can adapt to changes in the lines you're plotting (e.g., an automatic red fill_between everywhere BADTHING exceeds GOODTHING, without your having to figure out the index (30 or -30 in this example)).

Comment: My OP wasn't clear enough. I mainly want to get tail distributions right for both especially on the right side

Comment: Do you mean your y-values are wrong? That's a stats problem, not a programming problem.

Comment: Problem was both -- stats and to color tails. Fixed everything but only remaining thing is how to color right tail of y1 and y2 just like the sample figure?

Comment: Everything you need for the sample is in this answer code. You have an example of fill-between above a certain x-value, an example of fill-between between y2 and y1 and between y1 and 0. That's all the sample does.